# Product attribute filter not working?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, product-collection

I created product attribute called `model_pn_line` and added the values for this attribute during product adding.

My product collection code is like below.

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_product ->getId());
$productslist = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->addAttributeToSort('model_pn_line', 'asc');
```

The out put is like below.
[image]

My Question is how the 6 coming after **No 57**?

Comment: No 57 is product id? and what is the data in model_pn_line?

Comment: no 57 is the attribute value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess here and say that your attribute has the type text (or varchar or anything else that's not a number).
For text fields the sorting is done alphabetically. And based on your screenshot it seams to work perfectly because the string `57` is "smaller" than the string `6`.
If your attribute should behave as an integer then it should have the type `int`.

Comment: yes, i added integer number to Input Validation for Store Owner filed on attribute.Thank you.